# Adding additional NICs to a Virtual Machine in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtualization

Is it true, that even for Virtual Machine's created in the latest platform (ARM), that if you initially created the machine with 1 NIC, that there is no way to add additional NICs to the VM?

I found a few random (non-Microsoft) articles that seem to indicate this is the case, which if so... is kind of retarded.

So I wanted to make sure that I'm understanding this correctly.

If I have to start all over and build a new machine just to add a NIC, I might consider just using Amazon AWS as I can't imagine this being a limitation over there.

Comment: https://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2015/12/20/how-to-add-a-nic-to-an-azure-virtual-machine-arm/

Comment: That's actually one of the articles I found, and it says "The VM should already have at least two NICs. It’s not supported to pass from a single NIC VM to multiple NIC VM and vice versa".

In another article I read, it said that you can't even create a multi-NIC VM within the Azure web interface you have to do it via Powershell. 

I'm trying to get confirmation if anything has changed since these articles were written before nuking my perfectly fine and working VM just because I want to add a 2nd NIC (a basic feature that can be done easily in every other platform but Azure)

Answer (score 0):

> that if you initially created the machine with 1 NIC, that there is no
>   way to add additional NICs to the VM

It is true,  there is no way to add a NIC to an **existing** VM, and we can't via portal to create a VM with multiple NICs. But we can **create/recreate** the VM via powershell and **add** another NIC to it. Here is the powershell script:
`$rg = "jason-newgroup"
$loc = "japan east"
$nic01 = "nic01"
$nic02 = "nic02"
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name ‘jason-newgroup-vnet’ -ResourceGroupName ‘jason-newgroup’
$sub01id = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name ‘sub01’ -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id
$sub02id = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name ‘sub02’ -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id
$ip1 = '10.1.0.5'
$ip2 = '10.1.1.5'
$nic1 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic01 -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -SubnetId $sub01id -PrivateIpAddress $ip1
$nic2 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic02 -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -SubnetId $sub02id -PrivateIpAddress $ip2
$vmsize = "Standard_DS4_v2" 
$vmname = "jason-windows" 
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmname -VMSize $vmsize 
$VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $nic1.Id -Primary
$VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $nic2.Id
$osDiskName = "jason-newtest" 
$osDiskVhdUri = "https://jasonnewgroupdisks717.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jason-windows2016920165635.vhd" 
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -name $osDiskName -CreateOption attach -windows
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -VM $vm`
[image]
[image]

**Notice:**
The **VM size** determines the number of NICS that you can create for a VM. More information about how many NICS each VM size supports, please refer to the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/

Answer (score 0):

There is an update to this. You can now add nics to existing Azure VMs. See the documentation here for tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-vm